# Passing a class instance to a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Firstly, I am aware that there are other questions similar to this one, in fact, one of them with the same title but I couldn't get any help from the other questions.

I am working with Functional Mockup Interface. I have an Functional Mock-up Unit(FMU) which is basically an instance of a class in python.

I want to pass it to a function to get the Jacobian matrix but I am not able to pass an instance of the class to a function defined in a module. If I define a function like this in a module

```
# Function to take an FMU instance and do something using it's methods
def do_something_to_fmu(fmu):
    N=fmu.get_ode_sizes() # get_ode_sizes() is a function that returns a tuple
    return N
```

**The error I am getting is: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__**.

What's surprising is that if I define the very same function in the console it works. Another thing I should mention here is that I can't modify the class. It comes from another source i.e. the pyfmi library which takes a piece of modelica code and converts into an FMU.

I think the mistake lies in passing a class instance to a function and I am reading the documentation to find out what's going wrong but it would be a great help if someone could suggest a better way to get the jacobian from an FMU. (An FMU has a method to give the derivatives. What I am trying is to use this and numerically compute the Jacobian)

Thanks

Comment: Passing instances of classes (*objects*) as arguments to a function is not something new in any language. This is most certainly **not* the problem. Could you paste the *entire* traceback please?

Comment: The error message implies that you are subscripting a non-subscriptable object, so your hypothesis about the error is mistaken. Hence the need for the traceback (which you should add to the question, not forgetting to indent each line with 4 spaces for readability). It's also likely we will need to see the actual lines of code around which the exception occurs, which isn't anything in the question as currently framed.

Comment: You need to show the *full* traceback, as well as the code that creates `fmu` and passes it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are 'Passing a class instance' in the correct manner.
It's the same way you pass any other object. eg. a List
Anyway here's an example,

```
def myFunc(instance):
    print instance
    return type(instance)

myInstance = myClass() //creating an instance of myClass
print myFunc(myInstance)
```

The code will output the following